# Антонимы к пословицам

Tags: антонимы, пословицы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, антонимы для третьей пословицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Могу предположить, что ответ такой:

> Бросать слова на ветер.